# PyCharm Issue with Pipenv: Unable to Install New Packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pipenv

I use Pipenv to manage my packages and Pycharm as my IDE, but recently I started to experience something weird in Pycharm. When I add a new package in the `Pipfile` I generally use pycharm interface to installed it, but now I'm getting this error:

[image]

The versions that I'm using are the following:

- Python 3.10.13
- Pipenv version 2023.9.8
- Pycharm 2021.3.3

Comment: you're not actually using 3.10.13, the warning above says that pycharm uses python 3.7, and i think --json is from before that (i never saw it on pyenv). can you please check what command is pycharm running to install a package?

Comment: it is using this one: `source /Users/my_user/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_virtual_env/bin/activate
/Users/my_user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/bin/pyvenv graph --json`

Answer (score 0):

according to the command running, it's actually using version 3.7.12, and tries to use an argument --json which does not exists in that version. try looking at `~/.pyenv/versions/` and look for another version, if that doesn't work, then try removing the `--json` from the command. if none of those things worked then try creating a new venv, and then see what happens

Comment: The weird thing here is that Pycharm is running that command, and when it fails I receive the warning in the screenshot.

Comment: well yeah, pycharm doesn't really know what's going on, it basically just does ```f"pip install {package}"``` and returns to you the output. trust me, it's better to use the CMD or the shell and  install packages manually than to use some third party system for it. much easier and you know what's being installed

Comment: I was able to solve the problem, the solution was to uninstall the older version of PyCharm and install the latest version.  
Honestly I don’t know what was happening with my system.

Comment: oh, makes sense. i guess your pycharm configuration stayed the same from the older version to the new version. this is not a pycharm issue but a windows issue in that case, since windows does a ton of weird stuff with the local saved data